# How to release the new version of extension to market store?

Tags: magento2, extensions

I have a plugin with already 'Released to Store' with version 1.0.0.

Recently, I have submit a new version for this extension (version 1.0.2) and it already passed marketing preview. However the status of new version is still 'Approved' instead of 'Released to Store'.

[image]

So, how can I release the new version to store after passed the marketing review ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out the problem. My account need to complete some necessary information to enable to release the new version to store